# Breed won't appear on interface - Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

working on a project for varsity here and we're working in Netlogo. Basically i have a function that spawns medkits every 15 ticks, yet they don't appear on the screen. The code is basically as follows:

```
breed[kits kit]
kits-own [qtEner]

to Go
spawn-kits
end


to spawn-kits
  if (remainder ticks intervalo) = 0
  [
    create-kits 1
    [
      set nrg qtEner
      set shape "medkit"
      set size 1.5
      set heading 0
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      output-type "Created"
    ]
  ]
end
```

Would appreciate some feedback. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

What is your setup procedure? Do you have a `tick` somewhere to increment your counter?

Also, I think you may want `set qtEner nrg` if you want the kits to have their `kits-own` variable independently set.

This works for me:

```
breed[kits kit]
kits-own [qtEner]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
end

to Go
  spawn-kits
  tick
end


to spawn-kits
  if (remainder ticks 10) = 0
  [
    create-kits 1
    [
      set qtEner 5
      set shape "circle"
      set size 1.5
      set heading 0
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      print "Created"
    ]
  ]
end
```